# Error returning SQL Server result set using ODBC

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc

I am converting an existing app from Sybase to SQL Server 2008. The app uses ODBC to connect to the database. Simply changing the connection string has worked for most of the apps functionality but there is one bug that has me puzzled. I have created a simple example that shows the bug.

I have a stored procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.test_sel
as 
begin
  create table #cfg
  (
    Name  varchar(100) NULL,
    Dscr  varchar(50)  NULL
  )

  insert #cfg(Name, Dscr) 
  values('Config', 'Config description')

  select COUNT(*) as [Count] from #cfg

  return 0
end
```

and code that executes the stored procedure and loads the results into a DataTable:

```
{
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("test_sel", new OdbcConnection("Driver={SQL Server};Server=xxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx"));

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);

    using (cmd.Connection)
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
}
```

I would expect the message to show the value 1 and the DataTable to contain a single row. However the DataTable is empty (no result set is returned).

Now, if I comment out the `insert` statement in the stored procedure and rerun the code then I do get a result set returned containing one row, one column named count with a value of 0.

I have tried many variants of the stored procedure, using a permanent table rather than temporary, for example but each time the same thing happens - having the insert stops the stored procedure from returning a result set.

Changing the ODBC driver to SQL Server 2008 makes no difference. The code works as expected when using Sybase and when run in the MS SQL Server Management Studio.

After a google search I tried the following code:

```
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("test_sel", new SqlConnection("Server=xxx,5100;Database=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"));

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    using (cmd.Connection)
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
}
```

Now this works but I would rather not make code changes for this if I can help it because the app needs to work on both databases.

Can anyone suggest why the original code does not work? It really seems like something that simple should work OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options you can use to make this work (to me this seems like bug since `Fill` for both `OdbcDataAdapter` and `SqlDataAdapter` should work equally):

1) in the beginning of the procedure after the `begin` keyword add

```
set nocount on
```

2) Use the overload of `Fill` method that takes `DataSet` as parameter rather then the one that takes `DataTable`.

MSDN states: *The overload of Fill that takes DataTable as a parameter only obtains the first result*.

When `INSERT` is executed and `NOCOUNT` is off, information on how many rows were affected by the statement gets returned. So when you have this option off, count of rows will be reported 2 times (you can check that in SSMS, 'Messages' window), once for INSERT, second time for SELECT. It seems that first row count (from INSERT) somehow gets interpreted as first result set, this row count refers to `INSERT` statement not `SELECT` so there are no rows to return.

Comment: Just to add to Ivan G's answer from an ODBC perspective. In ODBC terms when nocount is off each insert/update/delete/select in a procedure is taken as a separate result-set. In ODBC terms you call SQLMoreResults to move through these result-sets so you can find out the count of affected rows.

Comment: Many thanks, adding SET NOCOUNT ON at the top of stored procedure body fix the problem.